# What makes spring boot do this conversion?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this issue with a form in spring boot. The input wiht `*{modelo}`

> org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert
>   value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'com.carrduci.gestionycontrol.model.Modelo'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for
>   value 'hola'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For
>   input string: "hola"

---

**This is my form:**

```
<form th:action="${modelo.id>0}? @{/costos/admin/modelo/modificar}:@{/costos/admin/modelo}" method="post" th:object="${modelo}">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                                <label >Modelo</label>
                                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" th:field="*{modelo}"> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('modelo')}" th:errors="*{modelo}" ></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                                <label >Categoria</label>
                                <select class="form-control input-lg" th:field="*{categoria}">
                                    <option th:each="cat:${categorias}"
                                            th:value="${cat.id}"
                                            th:text="${cat.categoria}"> </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
                                <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger BOTON_LIMPIAR" href="/index"> <span class="  glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancelar</a>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span> <span th:text="${modelo.id>0}? @{Modificar}:@{Guardar}"></span></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

---

**This is "Modelo"**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "modelo")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findById", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.id = :id")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByModelo", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.modelo = :modelo")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByIdTamano", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.idTamano = :idTamano")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByEspesorPastilla", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.espesorPastilla = :espesorPastilla")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByEspesorBoton", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.espesorBoton = :espesorBoton")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByLineasOMm", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.lineasOMm = :lineasOMm")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByCentroOFrente", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.centroOFrente = :centroOFrente")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByDiametroEspalda", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.diametroEspalda = :diametroEspalda")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByRectificado", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.rectificado = :rectificado")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByVelocidad", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.velocidad = :velocidad")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByMaterialEfecto", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.materialEfecto = :materialEfecto")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByFotoCelda", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.fotoCelda = :fotoCelda")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByInclinacion", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.inclinacion = :inclinacion")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByDiametroPata", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.diametroPata = :diametroPata")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByEspesorPata", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.espesorPata = :espesorPata")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByAlturaPata", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.alturaPata = :alturaPata")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByObservaciones", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.observaciones = :observaciones")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByCavidadDiametro", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.cavidadDiametro = :cavidadDiametro")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByCavidadProfundidad", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.cavidadProfundidad = :cavidadProfundidad")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Modelo.findByFigura", query = "SELECT m FROM Modelo m WHERE m.figura = :figura")})
public class Modelo implements Serializable {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull()
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    @Column(name = "modelo")
    private String modelo;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "materialEfecto")
    private String materialEfecto;
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "fotoCelda")
    private String fotoCelda;
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "inclinacion")
    private String inclinacion;
    @Size(max = 400)
    @Column(name = "Observaciones")
    private String observaciones;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "figura")
    private String figura;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "idTamano")
    private Integer idTamano;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Column(name = "espesorPastilla")
    private Float espesorPastilla;
    @Column(name = "espesorBoton")
    private Float espesorBoton;
    @Column(name = "lineasOMm")
    private Float lineasOMm;
    @Column(name = "centroOFrente")
    private Float centroOFrente;
    @Column(name = "diametroEspalda")
    private Float diametroEspalda;
    @Column(name = "rectificado")
    private Boolean rectificado;
    @Column(name = "velocidad")
    private Integer velocidad;
    @Column(name = "diametroPata")
    private Float diametroPata;
    @Column(name = "espesorPata")
    private Float espesorPata;
    @Column(name = "alturaPata")
    private Float alturaPata;
    @Column(name = "cavidadDiametro")
    private Float cavidadDiametro;
    @Column(name = "cavidadProfundidad")
    private Float cavidadProfundidad;
    @JoinTable(name = "relacionmodelos", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "idModelo", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "idModeloRelacionado", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Modelo> modeloCollection;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "modeloCollection")
    private Collection<Modelo> modeloCollection1;

    @JoinColumn(name = "idcategoria_producto", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private CategoriaProducto categoria;
    @JoinColumn(name = "agujas", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Refaccion agujas;
    @JoinColumn(name = "guia", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Refaccion guia;

    public Modelo() {
    }

    public Modelo(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Modelo(Integer id, String modelo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public Integer getIdTamano() {
        return idTamano;
    }

    public void setIdTamano(Integer idTamano) {
        this.idTamano = idTamano;
    }

    public Float getEspesorPastilla() {
        return espesorPastilla;
    }

    public void setEspesorPastilla(Float espesorPastilla) {
        this.espesorPastilla = espesorPastilla;
    }

    public Float getEspesorBoton() {
        return espesorBoton;
    }

    public void setEspesorBoton(Float espesorBoton) {
        this.espesorBoton = espesorBoton;
    }

    public Float getLineasOMm() {
        return lineasOMm;
    }

    public void setLineasOMm(Float lineasOMm) {
        this.lineasOMm = lineasOMm;
    }

    public Float getCentroOFrente() {
        return centroOFrente;
    }

    public void setCentroOFrente(Float centroOFrente) {
        this.centroOFrente = centroOFrente;
    }

    public Float getDiametroEspalda() {
        return diametroEspalda;
    }

    public void setDiametroEspalda(Float diametroEspalda) {
        this.diametroEspalda = diametroEspalda;
    }

    public Boolean getRectificado() {
        return rectificado;
    }

    public void setRectificado(Boolean rectificado) {
        this.rectificado = rectificado;
    }

    public Integer getVelocidad() {
        return velocidad;
    }

    public void setVelocidad(Integer velocidad) {
        this.velocidad = velocidad;
    }


    public Float getDiametroPata() {
        return diametroPata;
    }

    public void setDiametroPata(Float diametroPata) {
        this.diametroPata = diametroPata;
    }

    public Float getEspesorPata() {
        return espesorPata;
    }

    public void setEspesorPata(Float espesorPata) {
        this.espesorPata = espesorPata;
    }

    public Float getAlturaPata() {
        return alturaPata;
    }

    public void setAlturaPata(Float alturaPata) {
        this.alturaPata = alturaPata;
    }


    public Float getCavidadDiametro() {
        return cavidadDiametro;
    }

    public void setCavidadDiametro(Float cavidadDiametro) {
        this.cavidadDiametro = cavidadDiametro;
    }

    public Float getCavidadProfundidad() {
        return cavidadProfundidad;
    }

    public void setCavidadProfundidad(Float cavidadProfundidad) {
        this.cavidadProfundidad = cavidadProfundidad;
    }


    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Modelo> getModeloCollection() {
        return modeloCollection;
    }

    public void setModeloCollection(Collection<Modelo> modeloCollection) {
        this.modeloCollection = modeloCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Modelo> getModeloCollection1() {
        return modeloCollection1;
    }

    public void setModeloCollection1(Collection<Modelo> modeloCollection1) {
        this.modeloCollection1 = modeloCollection1;
    }

    public CategoriaProducto getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(CategoriaProducto categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public Refaccion getAgujas() {
        return agujas;
    }

    public void setAgujas(Refaccion agujas) {
        this.agujas = agujas;
    }

    public Refaccion getGuia() {
        return guia;
    }

    public void setGuia(Refaccion guia) {
        this.guia = guia;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Modelo)) {
            return false;
        }
        Modelo other = (Modelo) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Modelo{" + "id=" + id + ", modelo=" + modelo + ", idTamano=" + idTamano + ", espesorPastilla=" + espesorPastilla + ", espesorBoton=" + espesorBoton + ", lineasOMm=" + lineasOMm + ", centroOFrente=" + centroOFrente + ", diametroEspalda=" + diametroEspalda + ", rectificado=" + rectificado + ", velocidad=" + velocidad + ", materialEfecto=" + materialEfecto + ", fotoCelda=" + fotoCelda + ", inclinacion=" + inclinacion + ", diametroPata=" + diametroPata + ", espesorPata=" + espesorPata + ", alturaPata=" + alturaPata + ", observaciones=" + observaciones + ", cavidadDiametro=" + cavidadDiametro + ", cavidadProfundidad=" + cavidadProfundidad + ", figura=" + figura + ", modeloCollection=" + modeloCollection + ", modeloCollection1=" + modeloCollection1 + ", categoria=" + categoria + ", agujas=" + agujas + ", guia=" + guia + '}';
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public String getMaterialEfecto() {
        return materialEfecto;
    }

    public void setMaterialEfecto(String materialEfecto) {
        this.materialEfecto = materialEfecto;
    }

    public String getFotoCelda() {
        return fotoCelda;
    }

    public void setFotoCelda(String fotoCelda) {
        this.fotoCelda = fotoCelda;
    }

    public String getInclinacion() {
        return inclinacion;
    }

    public void setInclinacion(String inclinacion) {
        this.inclinacion = inclinacion;
    }

    public String getObservaciones() {
        return observaciones;
    }

    public void setObservaciones(String observaciones) {
        this.observaciones = observaciones;
    }

    public String getFigura() {
        return figura;
    }

    public void setFigura(String figura) {
        this.figura = figura;
    }



}
```

---

**I have two controllers**

This saves a new "Modelo"

```
@RequestMapping(value="admin/modelo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView nuevoModelo(
            @Valid Modelo modelo
            ,BindingResult br 
    ){  
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        //COMPROBAMOS SI EL MODELO EXISTE
        if (modeloService.modeloExist(modelo.getModelo())) {
            br.rejectValue("modelo", "error.modelo", "Ya hay un modelo con ese nombre");
        } 

        if (br.hasErrors()) {
            mav.setViewName("costos/modelo");
        }else{
            //GRABAMOS EL MODELO
            if (modeloService.saveModelo(modelo)) {
                mav.addObject("success", "Se registro el modelo con exito.");
                mav.addObject("modelo", new Modelo());
            } else {
                mav.addObject("Error", "Algo paso y no se pudo guardar el modelo");
            }
        }

    mav.addObject("modelo", new Modelo());

        mav.setViewName("costos/modelo");
        mav.addAllObjects(gds.costos_modelo(gds.getUser()));
        return mav;
    }
```

And this modify a "Modelo"

```
@RequestMapping(value="admin/modelo/modificar/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView nuevoModelo(
            @PathVariable("id") int id){

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

        if (modeloService.modeloExist(id)) {
            mav.addObject("modelo", modeloService.findModeloById(id));
        }else{
            mav.addObject("error", "El modelo no existe: "+id);
            mav.addObject("user", new Modelo());

        }

        //RECUERDA QUE EL SUBMIT DEL FORM SE CAMBIA SI EL ID ES 0, OSEA QUE
        // NO HAY ID.;
        mav.setViewName("costos/modelo");
        mav.addAllObjects(gds.costos_modelo(gds.getUser()));
            return mav;
    }
```

---

**What is happend?**

- If I put a "some string" in the "input text" throws an error.
- If I put a "number" in the "input text" works beautifully.
- Both controllers have the same issue.

---

**MORE INFO**

"Modelo" is generated automatically in netbeans, so my DB fields correspond in type(String in this case) vs Class.

> **What I´m doing wrong?**

I hope you guys can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically id property in your entity class is an Integer and you are trying to pass an non numeric value to it.

Comment: My `id` is an `int`, but not my property "modelo" in the form `*{modelo}`. That's where my problem is.